# change multiple columns in pandas dataframe to datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a dataframe of 13 columns and 55,000 rows I am trying to convert 5 of those rows to datetime, right now they are returning the type 'object' and I need to transform this data for machine learning I know that if I do

```
data['birth_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data[birth_date], errors ='coerce')
```

it will return a datetime column but I want to do it for 4 other columns as well, is there one line that I can write to call all of them? I dont think I can index like

```
data[:,7:12]
```

thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a function to convert multiple columns at the same time but I know that `read_csv` has a `parse_dates` argument that can take a list of all the columns you would like to convert when first importing your data.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to iterate through each column using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
data.iloc[:, 7:12] = data.iloc[:, 7:12].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

As part of [the changes in pandas 1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#try-operating-inplace-when-setting-values-with-loc-and-iloc), `iloc`/`loc` will no longer update the column dtype on assignment. Use column labels directly instead:

```
cols = data.columns[7:12]
data[cols] = data[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: quick question, in this case wouldn't it be better to use the map() method ?

Comment: `map` and `apply` can both accept functions which is why this confuses users like you. I only use `map` to do 'literal mapping' with a dictionary/Series. I only use `apply` for functions. `apply` has some extra functionality too.

Comment: With `errors='coerce'`, invalid dates are assigned to `NaT` - the 2nd example from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime) shows this. If `ignore` is used instead of `coerce`, it will ignore the fact that it is an invalid specification and just return a (possibly) invalid/incorrect date.

Comment: I've the same problem, but I only need to change the column name from string (e.g.: 2020-Q4) to datetime without affecting the rows. how can this be done ?

Answer (score 45):

```
my_df[['column1','column2']] =     
my_df[['column1','column2']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Note: of course the format can be changed as required.

Comment: how can I keep the other columns of my dataframe when I do that?

Comment: @JessicaVoigt left of the `=` only the selected columns are overwritten; the remaining columns in `my_df` will remain untouched. You could do `my_df[['new_1','new_2']] = my_df[['column1','column2']].apply(...)` to assign respectively to new columns.

Answer (score 19):

If performance is a concern I would advice to use the following function to convert those columns to date_time:

```
def lookup(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) for date in s.unique()}
    return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])

to_datetime: 5799 ms
dateutil:    5162 ms
strptime:    1651 ms
manual:       242 ms
lookup:        32 ms
```

Source: 
https://github.com/sanand0/benchmarks/tree/master/date-parse

Comment: The numbers don't look that impressive if the data frame is deep and dates are not normally distributed. I ran the code on my data frame (273771,), the to_datetime time was 1min13 sec vs the lookup was 59 sec.

Comment: @smishra Most likely this depends on your input data. If there are a lot of duplicates. SerialDev 's approach than is a fast lookup instead of a conversion.

Comment: This looks great. How are we passing the series object as s? df['Date'] = lookup(['Date'])?

Answer (score 12):

If you rather want to convert at load time, you could do something like this

```
date_columns = ['c1','c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']
data = pd.read_csv('file_to_read.csv', parse_dates=date_columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to extract all the columns your interested in from `data` then you can use pandas `applymap` to apply `to_datetime` to each element in the extracted frame, I assume you know the index of the columns you want to extract, In the code below column names of the third to the sixteenth columns are extracted. you can alternatively define a list and add the names of the columns to it and use that in place, you may also need to pass the date/time format of the the DateTime entries

```
import pandas as pd

cols_2_extract = data.columns[2:15]

data[cols_2_extract] = data[cols_2_extract].applymap(lambda x : pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%d %M %Y'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different from the accepted answer, loc also works:

```
dx.loc[:,['birth_date','death_date']] = dx.loc[:,['birth_date','death_date']].apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.iloc[:, 7:12]=data.iloc[:, 7:12].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 0):

**read_csv()**

Adding to @smishra answer. When importing .csv you can infer dates using `infer-datetime-format` as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571615/why-use-infer-datetime-format-when-importing-csv-file). This can only be used if the series has a consistent date format but will speedup the import of dates.

**read_excel()**

There is also the `read_excel()` function that can be used to import and process dates. You can pass the `parse_dates` parameter a list of columns name or numbers.

```
parse_dates = [7,8,9,10,11]
data = pd.read_excel('file_to_read.csv', sheet_name='Sheet1', parse_dates=parse_dates)
```