# Why use infer_datetime_format when importing csv file?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, csv, datetime

Where is the process difference between:

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

and

```
df=pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[0])
```

Why is the first import to [be faster](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)?
Since parse_dates already specifies where to look for a date.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for `pandas.read_csv` suggest why:

> **infer_datetime_format** : *boolean, default False*
>
> If True and parse_dates is enabled, pandas will attempt to infer the
>   format of the datetime strings in the columns, and if it can be
>   inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them. In some cases
>   this can increase the parsing speed by 5-10x.

Essentially, Pandas deduces the *format* of your `datetime` from the first element(s) and then assumes all other elements in the series will use the same format. This means Pandas does not need to check multiple formats when attempting to convert a string to `datetime`.

Remember, CSV files can only hold textual data, so a conversion to `datetime` (essentially a numeric type) will always be required.

Here's a demonstration:

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

L = ['2018-01-05', '2018-12-20', '2018-03-30', '2018-04-15']*5000

%timeit [parser.parse(i) for i in L]                   # 1.57 s
%timeit [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d') for i in L]  # 338 ms
```

Comment: does that mean, that without this command pandas would try to check for ever "row" if and if yes, than which datetime format is used in each row?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But without inferring, it will try multiple formats for each row until one works. It's not efficient.

Comment: Thanks for helping out here, I obviously need your help ;-) so does it mean that if a different date could show up this option should not be used? Maybe my question should have been, what is the downside of inferring?

Comment: Correct. If you have more than one format don't infer.