# How do you make dataframe match datetime dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

So I am writing a code for a Tkinter GUI, and in it, the code pulls data from FRED and uses it to present graphs. There is an option at the start to save the pulled data in a CSV file so you can run it without the internet. But when the code runs to use the CSV, something happens with the scale and it gives me a graph like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OjBB.png). I think it has something to do with the datetime data not being remembered. Current code situation follows:

Imports: from tkinter import *, from tkinter import ttk, pandas_datareader as pdr, pandas as pd, from datetime import datetime

Example of how data is called:

```
def getBudgetData():
    '''
    PURPOSE: Get the government budget balance data
    INPUTS: None
    OUTPUTS: The dataframe of the selected country
    '''
    
    global namedCountry

    # Reads what country is in the combobox when selected, then gives the index value so the correct
    # code is used in the graph
    namedCountry = countryCombo.get()
    selectedCountry = countryOptions.index(namedCountry)
    df = dfBudget[dfBudget.columns[selectedCountry]]

    return df
```

Code for getting/reading the dataframes

```
def readDataframeCSV():
    global dfCPIQuarterly, dfCPIMonthly, dfGDP, dfUnemployment, dfCashRate, dfBudget
    dfCPIQuarterly = pd.read_csv('dataframes\dfCPIQuarterly.csv', infer_datetime_format = True)  
    dfCPIMonthly = pd.read_csv('dataframes\dfCPIMonthly.csv')
    dfGDP = pd.read_csv('dataframes\dfGDP.csv')
    dfUnemployment = pd.read_csv('dataframes\dfUnemployment.csv')
    dfCashRate = pd.read_csv('dataframes\dfCashRate.csv')
    dfBudget = pd.read_csv('dataframes\dfBudget.csv')

def LogDiff(x, frequency):
    '''
    PURPOSE: Transform level data into growth
    INPUTS: x (time series), frequency (frequency of time series)
    OUTPUTS: x_diff (growth rate of time series)
    REFERENCE: Tau, Ran, & Chris Brookes. (2019). Python Guide to accompany
               introductary econometrics for finance (4th Edition). 
               Cambridge University Press.
    '''
    
    x_diff = 100*log(x/x.shift(frequency))
    x_diff = x_diff.dropna()
    return x_diff

def getAllFredData():
    '''
    PURPOSE: Extract all required data from FRED
    INPUTS: None
    OUTPUTS: Dataframes of all time series
    REFERENCE: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/
    '''
    
    global dfCPIQuarterly, dfCPIMonthly, dfGDP, dfUnemployment, dfCashRate, dfBudget
    
    # Country codes
    countryCPIQuarterlyCodes = ['AUSCPIALLQINMEI', 'NZLCPIALLQINMEI']
    countryCPIMonthlyCodes = ['CPALCY01CAM661N', 'JPNCPIALLMINMEI', 'GBRCPIALLMINMEI', 'CPIAUCSL']
    countryGDPCodes = ['AUSGDPRQDSMEI', 'NAEXKP01CAQ189S', 'JPNRGDPEXP',
                    'NAEXKP01NZQ189S', 'CLVMNACSCAB1GQUK', 'GDPC1']
    countryUnemploymentCodes = ['LRUNTTTTAUQ156S', 'LRUNTTTTCAQ156S', 'LRUN64TTJPQ156S',
                    'LRUNTTTTNZQ156S', 'LRUNTTTTGBQ156S', 'LRUN64TTUSQ156S']
    countryCashRateCodes = ['IR3TBB01AUM156N', 'IR3TIB01CAM156N', 'INTDSRJPM193N',
                    'IR3TBB01NZM156N', 'IR3TIB01GBM156N', 'FEDFUNDS']
    countryBudgetCodes = ['GGNLBAAUA188N', 'GGNLBACAA188N', 'GGNLBAJPA188N',
                    'NZLGGXCNLG01GDPPT', 'GGNLBAGBA188N', 'FYFSGDA188S']
    
    # Inflation
    dfCPIQuarterly = pdr.DataReader(countryCPIQuarterlyCodes,
                                        'fred', start, end)
        
    for country in countryCPIQuarterlyCodes:
        dfCPIQuarterly[country] = pd.DataFrame({"Inflation rate":LogDiff(dfCPIQuarterly[country], 4)})
            
            
    dfCPIMonthly = pdr.DataReader(countryCPIMonthlyCodes,
                                               'fred', start, end)
                
    for country in countryCPIMonthlyCodes:
        dfCPIMonthly[country] = pd.DataFrame({"Inflation rate":LogDiff(dfCPIMonthly[country], 12)})
    
        
    # GDP
    dfGDP = pdr.DataReader(countryGDPCodes, 
                           'fred', start, end)
         
    for country in countryGDPCodes:
        dfGDP[country] = pd.DataFrame({"Economic Growth":LogDiff(dfGDP[country], 4)})
            
    # Unemployment
    dfUnemployment = pdr.DataReader(countryUnemploymentCodes,
                                    'fred', start, end)
    
    # Cash Rate
    dfCashRate = pdr.DataReader(countryCashRateCodes,
                                 'fred', start, end)

    # Budget
    dfBudget = pdr.DataReader(countryBudgetCodes,
                              'fred', start, end)
    
    print('')
    saveToCSVLoop = True
    while saveToCSVLoop == True:
        saveToCSV = input('Would you like to save the dataframes to a CSV file so start-up will be quicker next (y or n): ')
        if saveToCSV == 'y':
            dfCPIQuarterly.to_csv('dataframes\dfCPIQuarterly.csv', index = True)
            dfCPIMonthly.to_csv('dataframes\dfCPIMonthly.csv', index = False)
            dfGDP.to_csv('dataframes\dfGDP.csv', index = False)
            dfUnemployment.to_csv('dataframes\dfUnemployment.csv', index = False)
            dfCashRate.to_csv('dataframes\dfCashRate.csv', index = False)
            dfBudget.to_csv('dataframes\dfBudget.csv', index = False)
            saveToCSVLoop = False
        elif saveToCSV == 'n':
            saveToCSVLoop = False
        else:
            print('\nNot a valid option')
            sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to help you without the csv data. It could be that the dates aren't saved properly, or aren't interpreted properly. Maybe you could try parsing the datetime first. It kind of looks like there are no years, or something that is expected to be the year is actually a month?

Since it starts at 1970, I have a feeling that it's interpreting your time as unix epoch, not normal yyyymmdd type dates. Try printing `dfCPIQuarterly` and see if it looks like a date. Maybe you shouldn't use `infer_datetime_format = True` when reading it from the csv, but it's hard to tell without more details.

Comment: how would I turn it into yyyymmdd typically?

Comment: Look here maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51571615/why-use-infer-datetime-format-when-importing-csv-file