# How to do forward filling for each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, imputation, forward-fill

I have a dataframe similar to below

```
id A   B   C   D E
1  2   3   4   5 5
1  NaN 4   NaN 6 7
2  3   4   5   6 6
2  NaN NaN 5   4 1
```

I want to do a null value imputation for columns `A`, `B`, `C` in a forward filling but for each group. That means, I want the forward filling be applied on each `id`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) for forward filling per groups for all columns, but if first values per groups are `NaN`s there is no replace, so is possible use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last casting to integers:

```
print (df)
   id    A    B    C  D    E
0   1  2.0  3.0  4.0  5  NaN
1   1  NaN  4.0  NaN  6  NaN
2   2  3.0  4.0  5.0  6  6.0
3   2  NaN  NaN  5.0  4  1.0

cols = ['A','B','C']
df[['id'] + cols] = df.groupby('id')[cols].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   id  A  B  C  D    E
0   1  2  3  4  5  NaN
1   1  2  4  4  6  NaN
2   2  3  4  5  6  6.0
3   2  3  4  5  4  1.0
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('id')[cols].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int))
   id  A  B  C
0   1  2  3  4
1   1  2  4  4
2   2  3  4  5
3   2  3  4  5
```

Or:

```
cols = ['A','B','C']
df.update(df.groupby('id')[cols].ffill().fillna(0))
print (df)
   id    A    B    C  D    E
0   1  2.0  3.0  4.0  5  NaN
1   1  2.0  4.0  4.0  6  NaN
2   2  3.0  4.0  5.0  6  6.0
3   2  3.0  4.0  5.0  4  1.0
```

Comment: I want to do it on some columns only like you last example, but when I use you're code I lose other columns, e.g. D to E

Comment: @H.Z. - It seems you forget for `df[['id'] + cols] =` and using `df = ` only.

Comment: I have that piece as well...it only adds one extra column to the end!

Comment: @H.Z. - Interesting, for me it working nice. Added alternative solution with `update`, can you check it?

Comment: Does the `fillna(0)` do anything in this example? I cannot see any values that were NaNs and are now zeros, in fact I cannot see any zeros at all. Is it OK to miss that out?

Comment: @dumbledad no, it does indeed nothing as there are no zeros for index 0

Comment: @jezrael: When I do this: `cols = ['SleepDate', 'InBedTimeFinal']
s3[['ID'] + cols] = s3.groupby('ID')[cols].ffill().fillna(0).astype(datetime64[ns])`. There is an error: `NameError: name 'datetime64` 'is not defined. What should I do?

Comment: @Jason - Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514173/change-multiple-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-to-datetime) solution

Comment: @Jason - Not understand, then why convert?

Comment: @jezrael: if I use this: `s3[['ID'] + cols] = s3.groupby('ID')[cols].ffill().fillna(0)`. There is an error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`.

Comment: @Jason - hmmm, not idea, is possible see some data for test?

Comment: @Jason had similar issue, I only had one column to fill so simply went with df['id'] = df.groupby('id')['my col'].ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)

Comment: @jezrael your solution doesn't work anymore for pandas versions > 0.25, since `groupby.ffill` no longer returns group values, so you get the same error as @Jason. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181262/groupby-with-ffill-deletes-group-and-does-not-put-group-in-index) for a workaround.