# GroupBy with ffill deletes group and does not put group in index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm running into a very strange issue ever since I have ported my code from one computer to another. I'm using pandas version 0.25.1 on this system, but am unsure on the pandas version I was using previously.

The issue is as follows:

I create a simple, unsorted (mock) dataframe on which I want to sort values and forward-fill all the NaN values.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np

In [2]: test = pd.DataFrame({"group" : ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
   ...:                      "count" : [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2],
   ...:                      "value" : [10, np.nan, 30, np.nan, 19, np.nan, 25, np.nan]})

In [3]: test
Out[3]:
  group  count  value
0     A      2   10.0
1     A      3    NaN
2     A      1   30.0
3     B      2    NaN
4     B      1   19.0
5     B      3    NaN
6     C      1   25.0
7     C      2    NaN
```

However, when I do that I lose the entire "group" column, and it does not reappear in my index either.

```
In [4]: test.sort_values(["group", "count"]).groupby("group").ffill()
Out[4]:
   count  value
2      1   30.0
0      2   10.0
1      3   10.0
4      1   19.0
3      2   19.0
5      3   19.0
6      1   25.0
7      2   25.0
```

I've also tried to use the following using fillna, but that gives me the same result:

```
In [5]: test.sort_values(["group", "count"]).groupby("group").fillna(method = "ffill")
Out[5]:
   count  value
2      1   30.0
0      2   10.0
1      3   10.0
4      1   19.0
3      2   19.0
5      3   19.0
6      1   25.0
7      2   25.0
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The issue seems to be with the ffill method, since I CAN use .mean() on the groupby and retain my groupings.

Comment: have a look here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html

Comment: @Shijith I'm aware of the documentation. In the documentation it always shows that the column that is grouped by will appear in the index, which is exactly what my code used to do in the past as well. Right now, however, the column simply disappears.

Comment: can you check you python version is above 3.6 `minimum supported Python version will be bumped to 3.6 `

Comment: @Shijith Running on Python 3.7 as we speak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IICU, you have to use 'update` to get the results back to the dataframe

```
test.update(test.sort_values(["group", "count"]).groupby("group").ffill())
print(test)
```

**Output**

```
group   count   value
0   A   2   10.0
1   A   3   10.0
2   A   1   30.0
3   B   2   19.0
4   B   1   19.0
5   B   3   19.0
6   C   1   25.0
7   C   2   25.0
```

Comment: Is this a new feature in pandas? And how would this generalize to multiple columns with values (which is what my actual problem has), do I just need to assign the values back to all columns by doing: `test[["value1", "value2", "value3"]]`  etc?

Comment: In that case, try this `test.update(test.sort_values(["group", "count"]).groupby("group").ffill())`

Comment: This is a new behavior: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#dataframe-groupby-ffill-bfill-no-longer-return-group-labels

Comment: Doesn't work; requires align on indices