# Stopping a forward fill based on a different string column changing in the DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

i'm new to Python so go easy!

I have a Dataframe like the following. I would like to forward fill the NaN's in the shares_owned column but stop when the string in df['ticker'] changes. And only start when another number appears in shares_owned again.

| date | ticker | shares_owned | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | EZY | NaN | £2 |
| 02/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £2.1 |
| 03/01/2020 | EZY | NaN | £2.12 |
| 04/01/2020 | EZY | NaN | £12.5 |
| 01/01/2020 | FTSE | NaN | £11 |
| 02/01/2020 | FTSE | NaN | £12 |
| 03/01/2020 | FTSE | 2 | £12.5 |
| 04/01/2020 | FTSE | NaN | £12.5 |

For example, the output table would look like this:

| date | ticker | shares_owned | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | EZY | NaN | £2 |
| 02/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £2.1 |
| 03/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £2.12 |
| 04/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £12.5 |
| 01/01/2020 | FTSE | NaN | £11 |
| 02/01/2020 | FTSE | NaN | £12 |
| 03/01/2020 | FTSE | 2 | £12.5 |
| 04/01/2020 | FTSE | 2 | £12.5 |

So far I have been trying to use the .fillna(method='ffill') to no avail.

Comment: Hi @Barnaby, so since you're new, you should read up on providing a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) meaning you should provide enough here to show that you've worked the problem, a starting point for your solution, what you expected, and what you got instead. Errors are gold.

Comment: You can group the dataframe on `ticker` then `ffill` the `shares_column`  per group: `df['shares_owned'] = df.groupby('ticker')['shares_owned'].ffill()`.

Comment: And this could be helpful... looks like they're trying to do the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181262/groupby-with-ffill-deletes-group-and-does-not-put-group-in-index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you note groups,  hence `groupby()` does the grouping
- within the group `fillna(method="fill")` within a `transform()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""date    ticker  shares_owned    price
01/01/2020  EZY NaN £2
02/01/2020  EZY 10  £2.1
03/01/2020  EZY NaN £2.12
04/01/2020  EZY NaN £12.5
01/01/2020  FTSE    NaN £11
02/01/2020  FTSE    NaN £12
03/01/2020  FTSE    2   £12.5
04/01/2020  FTSE    NaN £12.5"""), sep="\t")

df["shares_owned"] = df.groupby("ticker")["shares_owned"].transform(lambda s: s.fillna(method="ffill"))
```

#### output

|  | date | ticker | shares_owned | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 01/01/2020 | EZY | nan | £2 |
| 1 | 02/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £2.1 |
| 2 | 03/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £2.12 |
| 3 | 04/01/2020 | EZY | 10 | £12.5 |
| 4 | 01/01/2020 | FTSE | nan | £11 |
| 5 | 02/01/2020 | FTSE | nan | £12 |
| 6 | 03/01/2020 | FTSE | 2 | £12.5 |
| 7 | 04/01/2020 | FTSE | 2 | £12.5 |

Comment: You don't need `transform` with `lambda`, we can use `ffill` directly here :)